# Why AutoSuggestion List does not close on Enter in MFC?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, mfc

I have a MFC Dialog Application. I add a Edit Control in the Dialog and turn the autoSuggestion on by using following code

```
SHAutoComplete(txtPath.m_hWnd, SHACF_FILESYS_DIRS);
```

things work fine. But when I Scroll the Suggestion list and press Enter, The list does not close. How Can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to use Accelerator to catch the  Key Presses and perform the Desired action.
I modified the Enter Key behaviour into Tab key behaviour.

```
void CHDVRLauncherDlg::OnMyEnter() 
{  
  int btnID = 0;
  CWnd * pFocus = GetFocus();  

  if(pFocus != NULL)
    btnID = pFocus->GetDlgCtrlID();

  NextInTabOrder();      
}

void CHDVRLauncherDlg::NextInTabOrder()
{  
   CWnd* pWndNext = GetNextDlgTabItem(GetFocus());
   if(pWndNext) 
     pWndNext->SetFocus();
}
```

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102589) : How To Use the ENTER Key from Edit Controls in a Dialog Box